# Rotation using cropper js

Tags: javascript, meteor, cropperjs

I'm working with the croppers library, I have the problems implementing it on some Android devices the photo being taken vertically I get horizontal I tried to adapt the horizontal or vertical rotation part (90 or 180 degrees) with copper js but not Succeeded at all.

[video](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B4pYg956DHc4MTZtQ0gzcnE3QXVIWmxpcUFPODQwME8xb0U4)

I'm working my code in meteor I leave a part of the code.
html part

```
<div class=" col-xs-6 ">
    <div>
        {{#if photo_2}}
        <img class="img-responsive" src='{{photo_2}}' alt="" style="width:1531px;height:114px;"/>
        {{else}}
        <img class="img-responsive" src="/persona2.png" alt="" />
        {{/if}}
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-12">
        <button type="" class="btn-default btn-picture btn" id="btn2"><i class="fa fa-plus plus" aria-hidden="true"></i></button>
    </div>
</div>
<input type="hidden" id="photoid">
<input id="file-upload" style="display: none;" type="file" accept="image/*" />
<div id="snackbar">
    <img class="img-responsive cameraphoto"  id="cameraphoto" src="/camera-icon-55.png" alt="" />
    <img class="img-responsive" id="explorer" onclick="$('#file-upload').click();" src="/camera-icon-56.png" alt="" />
    <img class="img-responsive"  id="delete" src="/delete.png" />
</div>

<div id="crops" style="display: none; background-color: black;height: 100vh;">
    <canvas id="canvas" height="5" width="5" style="display: none;"></canvas>
    <img id="target" style="max-width: 100%" />
    <img id="targeted" style="max-width: 100%" />

    <div style="position: absolute; margin-top: 145px; bottom: 20px; width: 100%;text-align: center;">
        <center>
            <img class="img-responsive" id="Save" src="/save.png" alt="" style="width: 48px;margin-left: -78px;"/>
            <img class="img-responsive" id="cancel"  src="/cancel.png" alt="" style="width: 54px;margin-left: 62px;margin-top: -50px;"/>
            <image id="Browser" src=""/>
        </center>
        <input type="hidden" id="photoid">
    </div>

    <input type="hidden" name="imgX1" id="imgX1" />
    <input type="hidden" name="imgY1" id="imgY1" />
    <input type="hidden" name="imgWidth" id="imgWidth" />
    <input type="hidden" name="imgHeight" id="imgHeight" />
    <input type="hidden" name="imgrotate" id="imgrotate" />
    <input type="hidden" name="imgscaleX" id="imgscaleX" />
    <input type="hidden" name="imgscaleY" id="imgscaleY" />
</div>
```

javaScript code

```
 'click .cameraphoto' : function(e , instance)   {
       var photoid = $('#photoid').val();
        var options = {
            width: 800,
            height: 600,
  };
    MeteorCamera.getPicture(options, function (error, data) {
      if (!error)   {
          $('#photos').hide();
          $('#crops').show();
          document.getElementById('target').src = "";
          document.getElementById('target').src = data;
          $('#target').cropper(  {
            aspectRatio: 1 / 1,
            minCropBoxWidth : 150,
            minCropBoxHeight :150,
            crop: function(e)  {
                $('#imgX1').val(e.x);
                $('#imgY1').val(e.y);
                $('#imgWidth').val(e.width);
                $('#imgHeight').val(e.height);
                $('#imgrotate').val(e.rotate);
                $('#imgscaleX').val(e.scaleX);
                $('#imgscaleY').val(e.scaleY);
            }
          // cropper.rotate(instance.state.get("left"));
      //    rotateTo(instance.state.get("left"))
         });
        }
     });
    }
'change #file-upload' :function(e) {
      $(".loader").fadeIn("slow");
      encodeImageFileAsURL();
      function encodeImageFileAsURL(){
        var filesSelected = document.getElementById("file-upload").files;
        if (filesSelected.length > 0) {
          var fileToLoad = filesSelected[0];
          var fileReader = new FileReader();
          fileReader.onload = function(fileLoadedEvent)      {
                 $('#photos').hide();
                 $('#crops').show();
                 $(".loader").fadeOut("slow");
                 document.getElementById('target').src = "";
                 document.getElementById('target').src = fileLoadedEvent.target.result;
                 $('#target').cropper( {
                  aspectRatio: 1 / 1,
                  minCropBoxWidth : 150,
                  minCropBoxHeight :150,
                  crop: function(e)  {
                     $('#imgX1').val(e.x);
                     $('#imgY1').val(e.y);
                     $('#imgWidth').val(e.width);
                     $('#imgHeight').val(e.height);
                     $('#imgrotate').val(e.rotate);
                     $('#imgscaleX').val(e.scaleX);
                     $('#imgscaleY').val(e.scaleY);
                  }
                });

            }
          fileReader.readAsDataURL(fileToLoad);}}
    },
    'click #Save' : function(e) {
        $(".loader").fadeIn("slow");
        e.preventDefault();
        var photoid = $('#photoid').val();
        var x1 = $('#imgX1').val();
        var y1 = $('#imgY1').val();
        var width = $('#imgWidth').val();
        var height = $('#imgHeight').val();
        var rotate = $('#imgrotate').val();
        var scaleX = $('#imgscaleX').val();
        var scaleY = $('#imgscaleY').val();
        var canvas = $("#canvas")[0];
        var context = canvas.getContext('2d');
        var img = new Image();
        img.src = $('#target').attr("src");
        img.onload = function ()    {
           canvas.height = height;
           canvas.width = width;
           context.drawImage(img, x1, y1, width, height, 0, 0, width, height);
           var dataURL = canvas.toDataURL("image/jpeg");
           //console.log('canvas',dataURL);
           var photo =  {
                    srcData : dataURL,
                    userid : Meteor.userId(),
                    photo_id : photoid
            }
            Meteor.call('updatePhoto',photo,function(err)  {
              if (!err) {
                 $('#photos').show();
                 $('#crops').hide();
                  $('#imgX1').val('');
                  $('#imgY1').val('');
                  $('#imgWidth').val('');
                  $('#imgHeight').val('');
                  $('#imgrotate').val('');
                  $('#imgscaleX').val('');
                  $('#imgscaleY').val('');
                  canvas.height = 0;
                  canvas.width = 0;
                 //page relod is better than
                 FlowRouter.go('/search');
                 FlowRouter.go('/addphoto');
            }
            });
        }
    },
    'click #cancel' :function() {
        $('#photos').show();
        $('#crops').hide();
        document.getElementById('target').src="";
        FlowRouter.go('/search');
        FlowRouter.go('/addphoto');
    },
```

Comment: Please post solutions as answers not as updates to the question. This is to avoid confusion. You can find your changes in your [revisions](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/45019008/revisions). Thank you.

Comment: Ready as I can to mark my own question as answer after finding the solution and editing it.?

Comment: The point of your question is to illustrate the problem. The point of an answer is to answer your problem. Seeing both the problem and the answer on the same page helps. If you remove the problem and replace with a solution then it's of no use to anybody. Please post the solution as an answer and mark it as accepted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My solution was based on the following

```
'click #rotateL': function(e, instance){
      $('#target').cropper('rotate', -90);
    },
    'click #rotateR': function(e, instance){
      $('#target').cropper('rotate', 90);
    },
'click #Save' : function(e) {
        $(".loader").fadeIn("slow");
        e.preventDefault();
        var photoid = $('#photoid').val();
        var canvas = $('#target').cropper('getCroppedCanvas');
        console.log(canvas)
        var dataURL = canvas.toDataURL("image/jpeg");
        var photo =  {
                 srcData : dataURL,
                 userid : Meteor.userId(),
                 photo_id : photoid
         }

            Meteor.call('updatePhoto',photo,function(err)  {
              if (!err) {
                 $('#photos').show();
                 $('#crops').hide();
                  canvas.height = 0;
                  canvas.width = 0;
                 //page relod is better than
                   //document.getElementById('target').src="";
                 FlowRouter.go('/search');
                 FlowRouter.go('/addphoto');
            }
            });
    },
```